# Typescript error when using immer for a Redux' reducer

Tags: typescript, redux, immer.js

I'm trying to use Immer with Redux in a Typescript project.

Redux reducer could be typed as:

```
Reducer<State, Action>
```

I should be able to create an equivalent reducer with [Immer's produce function](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/example-reducer) which allows us to mutate a draft copy. But the types don't match. Error: "Undefined is not assignable to ..." This might be related to redux passing undefined as an argument for state at the beginning. If the reducer doesn't match `Reducer<State, Action>` I can't pass it to `createStore`

Typescript version 3.5.3.

How can I elegantly solve this? 
[image]

Answer (score 4):

When using the curried form of the `produce` function (passing a function as the first argument) you can pass a second argument for the default value. This can solve type mismatch when Redux calls your reducer with an undefined value on initialization.

```
const initState = {
    text: "hello"
}

type State = {
    text: string
} 
type Action = {
    type: "newUrl"
    text: string 
}

const reducer: Reducer<State, Action> = produce( 
    (draftSt: Draft<State>, action: Action) => {
        switch(action.type){
            case "newUrl": 
                draftSt.text = action.text
                break 
        }
    }, 
    initState
)
```

The reducer can than be passed safely to `createStore` or `configureStore`.

Comment: I can only seem to get this to work if the `State` is a concrete type. If you swap it out for a generic type, the errors return. Take for example the following:

`function injectImmer = <S>(reducer: Reducer<S>, initialState: S) => produce((draft: Draft<S>, action) => {
    reducer(draft, action);
  }, initialState);`

This causes errors with the `initialState` saying it must be of type `Immutable<S>`

Comment: @AndrewCraswell, It was challenging, but Immer also exports a generic... Immutable<T>. Use it for parameters. This should work: ```const injectImmer = <S extends object>(reducer: (s:Immutable<S>, a:any)=>S, initialState: Immutable<S>) => produce(
 (draft: Draft<S>, action) => { 
  reducer(draft, action); 
 }, 
 initialState
)
```

Comment: @AndrewCraswell Basically you can pass a regular type to an immutable/deepReadonly type, but not the other way around

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
 import produce from 'immer';

const reducer = (state = initialState, action: AnyAction) : State  => {
   return produce(state, (draft) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'Execute':
          draft.isFetching = true;
          break;
        case 'Success':
          draft.isFetching = false;
          break;
        case 'Failure':
          draft.isFetching = false;
          break;
        default:
          draft;
      }
    });

export default reducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to make it work, currently i return produce from the reducer

```
const reducer = (state, action) => produce(state, (draft) => {})
```

Comment: Strange. I'd expect a library as popular as Immer to solve such an issue.

Comment: @BenCarp Actually i just messed around with your example and it seems that if you include a `default case with return state` it will compile, can you try it and let me know?

Comment: @BenCarp make sure you provide a default state for the initial call of the reducer

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F2EKfzQbS2I35WoUoD4atwIUutEHyecj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @BenCarp If you don't wrap the draft in `Draft` type does it work?

Comment: 1. As you can see in the screenshot, it doesn't work on my TS 3.5.3. 
2. Setting a default value for Immer's draft, doesn't make much sense to me. the state argument that is passed should be a draft copy with proxies. 
3. While you can add a default clause and return state, at the end of produce it should returns an immutable value anyway, even if you have done nothing. What I'm trying to say is that while this code might make sense to Typescript it doesn't make much sense to me :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205190/discussion-between-ben-carp-and-asaf-aviv).

Answer (score 1):

Normally, `produce` returns the state, so we do not need to return anything. Hovever that causes error in typescript, because if any cases in reducer does not return anything, typescript will evaluate that, one of your reducer's return value type might be `undefined`.

the solution is at the end of each case, you explicitly return state:

```
return state,
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I recalled that the official [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) has a `createReducer` helper which uses Immer internally. Looking at their code gives a hint at how they solved this issue.

```js
import createNextState, { Draft } from 'immer'

export function createReducer<S>(
  initialState: S,
  ...): Reducer<S> {
  ...

  return function(state = initialState, action): S {
    // @ts-ignore createNextState() produces an Immutable<Draft<S>> rather
    // than an Immutable<S>, and TypeScript cannot find out how to reconcile
    // these two types.
    return createNextState(state, (draft: Draft<S>) => {
      const caseReducer = actionsMap[action.type]
      return caseReducer ? caseReducer(draft, action) : undefined
    })
  }
}
```

(see the [code here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/master/src/createReducer.ts#L107). I've shortened irrelevant parts with "..." for brevity).

You can see here their helper function returns a normally structured reducer whose primary job is just to pass the `state` to the `createNextDraft` function. Interestingly enough, this is just importing the `default` from Immer, so it's just an alias for the `produce` function.

See below for the example of how I used this:

```js
import produce, { Draft } from 'immer';

const reducer: Reducer<State, AnyAction> = (state: State = initialState, action: AnyAction) => {
   return produce(state, (draft: Draft<State>) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'Execute':
          draft.isFetching = true;
          break;
        case 'Success':
          draft.isFetching = false;
          break;
        case 'Failure':
          draft.isFetching = false;
          break;
      }
    });
```